# Using Bootstrap 3 LESS in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

With most versions of Bootstrap 2, I could use dotless in a prebuild step to compile and minify my LESS files in an ASP.NET MVC project.

With Bootstrap 3 out, dotless is (currently) incapable of compiling the version of LESS used in the project.  The dotless project seems to be [becoming unsupported](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/322).  I am interested in incorporating a technology that I can use as a prebuild step to compile less into css that works with Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 update 3 automatically compiles .less-files if you open them in the editor and save. In other words, you can do it during editing, before even starting to build at all. I'm not sure if it does it during build or not though.

Comment: @Alxandr Thanks for the tip - I'm looking at the web essentials extension now.

Comment: As said, you shouldn't need the extension. If you just update visual studio (a free update given that you have VS 2012), it'll come built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alxandr said, I ended up just using an updated version of VS 2012 to compile my less files while editing.  I also installed the Web Essentials extension to get better less support in the editor.